# What is the best way to handle source control of an external dependency for a C++ Visual Studio 2019 Solution using Git?

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, cmake

TL;DR: what is the best way to handle external dependencies in C++ Visual Studio projects in the context of source control? Ideally I want other people/devices to be able to just clone my repository, open the .sln file with Visual Studio 2019 and press F5 to compile without having to modify the compilation links for external libraries etc. each time a new clone is made.

---

I want to use an external library (GLFW, https://github.com/glfw/glfw) in a C++ Project in a Visual Studio 2019 Solution, and I want the project to be easily sharable via Git, both for other devices and other people.

There seems to be a few different approaches to handling this:

1. **Download the binaries and simply store them in my `external/glfw` folder.** This makes linking and including easy. The downside is that this requires manual updates and I would prefer to not redistribute someone else's binaries.
2. **Use Git submodules/subtree to include the glfw source code in my `external/glfw` folder.** My problem here is that I don't know of an easy way to compile the glfw source code as part of my Visual Studio build process since glfw uses CMake, and it doesn't seem to be possible to add a CMake project to a Visual Studio Solution unless the entire solution uses CMake which I want to avoid.
3. **Make a separate repository just for compiling the external libraries.** This repository would exist merely to compile external libraries, and the main repository would then use git submodules/subtree to fetch the appropriate binaries/libraries into `external/glfw`. The problem with this approach is that the overhead of managing a separate repository just for the purpose of compiling external libraries seems excessive.

Approach 2 holds the most appeal as it is simple yet flexible, however, I have been unable to make it work in Visual Studio since I can't seem to add a CMake Project to an existing solution. Is there a way to compile external CMake projects *when needed*, and have that script automatically execute when I press F5 in Visual Studio?

Comment: Dependencies are usually compiled once and then tested outside your project, then included in the main project if everything works. This can be automated so that updates are easy.

Comment: How can it be automated?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest what you seem to have partially deduced.  Instead of using your existing Visual Studio project/solution directly, convert your build to CMake and use a submodule.

Converting basically entails writing a CMakeLists.txt file with your build instructions, and you'll have one line in there that makes it traverse into the submodule.  When you run CMake, it'll configure your code as well as the submodule, and generate a Visual Studio project that compiles and links both.

Added bonus is your code will be one step closer to being cross-platform too, since CMake will just as easily generate build systems for Mac, WSL, Linux, etc.